# Code signing helper apps for Apple Sandbox on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, helper, sign

I have an app I need to run at startup, and I am converting to Sandboxing.

I have a helper app created, and working fine when I do not code sign my app.

To codesign, it looks like I have to create provisioning profiles - one for the helper and one for the actual app.

Since these dont match, I cant get both to match, and am unable to have the helper app launch the main app.

I have tried to re-sign the helper:

codesign -f -vv -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:" -i "com.mydomain.myhelper" --entitlements myhelper/myhelper.entitlements myhelper.app

And get the error: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

I have re-created the helper from scratch, with no results.

How can I do this helper app and get it signed? There seems no documentation on this process.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this same problem yesterday when submitting an app. I think I finally figured it out. Here's what I did:

- Archive the app as normal
- Right click on the archive in the organizer and select **Show in Finder**
- Right click on the archive and show contents and burrow all the way down to your `HELPERAPP embedded.provisionprofile` and delete it.

Then from the Terminal codesign like this:

> codesign -f -s "3rd Party mac Developer Application:" -i
>   "com.company.**YOUR_MAIN_APP**" --entitlements
>   **YOUR_MAIN_APP_ENTITLEMENTS_PATH_IN_YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER**  **THE_ARCHIVED_HELPER.app_PATH**

This did pass validation and let me upload. I'm waiting for review so we'll see if this worked.

Comment: having the same issue... I don't see my HELPERAPP embedded.provisionprofile anywhere in the archive. Could you please explain in more details howto sign a helper app together with main app? Despite all the efforts after a week of trial and error I still get storeagent: Unsigned app ... Very frustrating.